# If more of one thing is good but less of another is good too

Tags: math, algebra

Here's a seemingly simple pondering.
If one item is more valuable the higher it is (i.e., `a=5` is worth more than `a=2`) and another item is more valuable the lower it is (i.e., `b=2` is worth more than `b=5`), what is an equation that will calculate how "good" the item pair is?

A couple of approaches:

- The perfect combination will be at 0.
- Higher result is better.
- Lower result is better.

Here's a physical example, bicyles:

- The lower the weight of a bicycle, the faster it performs. Also, the higher the gear ratio, the faster it performs. So:

  - One bike, **bike a**, has a weight of 29 and the highest gear (i.e., left*right, basically the same as gear ratio for our purposes) of 24.
  - Another, **bike b** has a weight of 26 and the highest gear of 25.

Which bike, assuming that weight and gear ratio matter the exact same in determining bike speed, will offer a fast speed?

Comment: I think 42 is the answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think you're onto something. In all seriousness, though, why the downvotes? I followed all the question guidelines; I listed what I tried/thought, examples, etc.

Comment: the problem presumably is that this is only math, not programming, and thus it's considered off-topic.

Comment: Oh, it's programming--because it's a calculation that a python program would theoretically be running based on a dataset. But I suppose I see what you mean. Is there some sort of StackExchange for 'math'?

Comment: I won't downvote users with low rep, but this doesn't really raise a programming question. It just seems like a general discussion about linear optimization problems.

Comment: In that case I wonder why we have `math` and even `algebra` tags. It seems that it is impossible to ask question with these tags without 99% risk of closing it almost immediately

Comment: @mvp That's the reason why I thought it would be appropriate to ask at all...hmm.

Comment: @mvp - this is what [compsci](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) and [maths](http://math.stackexchange.com/) are for.

Comment: I get about other sites like math - that's not what I am talking about. I wonder why StackOverflow (where we are now) even has `math` and `algebra` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As given, this question does not have definitive answer.

However, if you can define how important one metric compared to another, then it has a solution. For example, weight can have a metric of -50 (negative because the lower the better), and gear metric of 30. In that case total price can be defined as

```
v1*m1 + v2*m2 + ...
```

and the higher that total price is, the better.

Comment: Could something as simple as +1 and -1 work?

Comment: yes, that would work. metrics can be anything